# RPI fswebcam create unique filename from string

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am currently working on a Python script where I read a string and save it in name.
After this step I would like to take a photo with FSWebcam and this should be saved with the variable name.
I have already done the script uncomplicated, now the SD card has been defective and I start from new but I can no longer get it.

It has to be a small change, I didn't need any complicated commands or the like just the right puncture on string NAME or the command at the end from fswebcam was the solution.

```
import os

NAME="testname"

os.system('fswebcam -r 3840x2160 --no-banner --jpeg 100 /home/md/pictures/$NAME.jpg')
```

What you see here is just an example script to get the function up and running, if that works I build it into my main script.

Thank you and best regards
Dominik

Comment: What are you trying to acchieve and what have you already tried? What has been the output of the example code you've supplied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use an [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/):

```
os.system(f'fswebcam -r 3840x2160 --no-banner --jpeg 100 /home/md/pictures/{NAME}.jpg')
```

Comment: Ah now I see my mistake I forgot the F string ... The variant with the curly brackets I had already tried but not working - now I know why

Thank you very much! :)